# Get Grid Feature by ftype, not id

Tags: extjs

I am writing a generic class which is derived from ExtJS grid, and I have to check that the `grouping` feature is used during toolbar instantiation (if `grouping` is enabled, I want to auto-add two buttons to collapse/expand all groups).

```
var groupingFeature = me.getView().getFeature("grouping")
if(groupingFeature && me.store.grouper) {
    me.toolbar.insert(0,[{
        iconCls:'icon-plus',
        handler:function() {
            groupingFeature.expandAll();
        }
    },{
        iconCls:'icon-minus',
        handler:function() {
            groupingFeature.collapseAll();
        }
    }]);
}
```

But the grouping feature is not selected, because `getFeature` only works with ID (and I can't rely that a special id is added to every grouping feature).

Is there a way to get the feature by `ftype`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could search by `ftype` in a loop over the features array or use the **private** Method `findFeature` of the Ext.grid.View, which is doing this.
By the extjs [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-findFeature):

> Finds a features by ftype in the features array

So using this function, you should get you the required information.

```
var view = me.getView();
var groupingFeature = view.findFeature("grouping");
```